# React JS - custom accordion content won't slide open

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Here's what I've have so far - Full working view https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-elbakyan-v3h96

Accordion component:

```
const Accordion = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className={"wrapper"}>
      <ul className={"accordionList"}>
        {data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li className={"accordionListItem"} key={item.title}>
              <AccordionItem {...item} />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const AccordionItem = ({ content, title }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isOpened: false
  });

  return (
    <div
      className={cn("accordionItem", state.isOpened && "opened")}
      onClick={() => setState({ isOpened: !state.isOpened })}
    >
      <div className={"lineItem"}>
        <h3 className={"title"}>{title}</h3>
        <span className={"icon"} />
      </div>
      <div className={"inner"}>
        <div className={"content"}>
          <p className={"paragraph"}>{content}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I click on the accordion item nothing happens. I can see the content appears in inspect and the state changes as expected but it doesn't slide down. Did I miss something in my css or component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I was able to achieve. You may not like it completely(animations). But things seems sorted

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-babbage-2zt4f?file=/src/styles.css

props name was not right for accordion body

and styles need to be changes once the accordion is in open state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add or remove the className `inner` when `state.isOpen` so you can see your content